# Black blank screen and crash on iPhone 4 for any app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

This has happened with Xcode Beta (7.0) and Xcode (6.4).

I'm trying to debug my app with my iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2) and I set my Deployment Target under iOS 7.0. When I run my app, I can't see the LaunchScreen but instead it's a black blank screen and then it crashes.

I'm not giving any piece of code, because when I create **a new default project**, setting the Deployment Target right, **I get the same crash**.

> 2015-09-13 16:06:07.026 GafasApp2[243:60b] -[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d83420
>   2015-09-13 16:06:07.033 GafasApp2[243:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d83420'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x30a57f83 0x3b208ccf 0x30a5b917 0x30a5a203 0x309a9768 0x85cc3 0x332e4587 0x332e3edb 0x332de56b 0x3327a6e9 0x33279851 0x332ddca9 0x35892aed 0x358926d7 0x30a22a67 0x30a22a03 0x30a211d7 0x3098bebf 0x3098bca3 0x332dced1 0x332d814d 0x86fbd 0x3b715ab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I've been always developing with iPad air 2 but now I need my iPhone 4 to test some things, but I can't use it as I mentioned.

Do you have any clue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does adding an [exception beakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) help to find the problem? It looks like you are calling a method that does not exist? Does this happen in the simulator/other devices?

Comment: Yes... now I feel like a dumb, I had to set a breakpoint but since I'm kind of new in iOS development... I didn't think that. It's the default code which on `AppDelegate.m` which was crashing, could you develop an answer and I'll mark it as accepted? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try running the app in a different device and one of the simulators. This will let you know if the problem is one specific device.

Second, the main problem appears to be that your are calling a method that does not exist. Add an [exception brreakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html). This should break where the unrecognized selector is called.